# Getting Energy values from the Allegro ACS37800

Tags: power, measurement, energy, meter, allegro

I am currently using the [Allegro ACS37800](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/sense/current-sensor-ics/zero-to-fifty-amp-integrated-conductor-sensor-ics/acs37800) IC to monitor power, from what I found on the datasheets and from the internet this IC is capable of calculating the voltage, current, and power. I actually want to monitor the accumulated power (energy). I don't want to calculate that on the MCU side. Does anyone have had a similar experience?

Comment: Calculating energy is normally done on the MCU side so, why would you want to do it differently?

Comment: I used another IC in the past that efficiently calculated the energy, that's why I thought there might be a way to do it with Allego. Doing the calculation on the MCU side will make us lose some precision especially if we don't use a high sampling rate, which is my case. I have limitations in getting power samples from Allegro with a high rate, and more limitations to make calculations fast enough to not lose a new sample.

Comment: You can heavily low-pass filter the power output and integrate to get joules at a much more leisurely pace if you want.

Comment: That requires a HW change and I am not sure it will help me monitor consumed energy instantaneously.

Comment: There is no such thing as instantaneous consumed energy; power, yes but, energy, no.

Comment: I know, although I need to visualise that energy almost every second